# How to convert source codes in GitHub to Jar (twitter4j 4.06)

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to get the latest Jar file for twitter4j 4.06. They haven't released the 4.06 Jar file but they have all the source code in github. I want to know how to convert these source codes to Jar the same way they have it for the stable Jar file in their website version 4.04.

Their website Jar file 4.04:
http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

Github 4.06 files:
https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j

Comment: They are using Apache Maven. Do you tried to build it with Maven? Do you have a specific error or a general problem? Pleas be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Maven Project.

Install Maven on your machine, Checkout the code locally, and run `mvn clean package`

It would give you a Jar in your .m2 folder against the following

```
<groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
<artifactId>twitter4j</artifactId>
<version>4.0.6</version>
```